# Android | Add line on the navbar

Tags: android, xml

In my v27\style.xml I have the following code to set a white navbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
</style>
```

It works, but the white navbar "joins" with the white background. I would to add an horizontal line on the navbar, in each activity. How can I do?

This is what I would (from Youtube), I highlighted it with red rectangle:
[image: YouTube App]

Comment: What do u mean a line? An underline? A separator line?

Comment: A separator line, I highlighted it in the screenshot.

Comment: check the answers..

Answer (score 0):

I think for cases like these you may need to have a custom toolbar layout so that you can optimise the layout whichever way you like.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvToolBarTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Toobar"
    android:fontFamily="@font/filson_pro_book"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to add an horizontal line each time you open the nav drawer:

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
    android:layout_gravity = "bottom/>
```

If you want the line to be on half of the screen (only on the nav)- add it inside the nav.

If you want the line to be on the whole screen (as you marked in the picture)- add it after adding the nav.

Comment: Okay, but the nav bar is added automatically... Do I have to add this code to each layout?

Comment: As I said- if you want it on the whole screen then paste it in the main_layout after the code of the nav.

Comment: If you want it only in the nav, then add it inside the layout of the nav.

Comment: Would be much easier to explain if you would add the xml code of the layouts.

Comment: I've different layouts. For example, one layout has only a LinearLayout with inside a TextView and I set the navbar color with the code in my question. I was hoping there was a general parameter to insert in the style file.

Answer (score 0):

Since API 27 there is an attribute in the style called `navigationBarDividerColor` that allows to do that. You can complement it with the `navigationBarColor` to make it look like the one in your screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarDividerColor">#DBDBDB</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]